# How to put an object into template via Jinja2 in Django app using Coffin

Tags: django, tags, thumbnails, jinja2

I use **Coffin** to integrate **Jinja2** with **Django** application. I want to use **sorl** application in my Jinja2 template. So i decided to write my own Extension for tag {% thumbnail %}. I decided to use a great *WithExtension* as an example which come out from a box with Coffin.

My extension:

```
class ThumbnailExtension(Extension):

tags = set(['thumbnail'])

def parse(self, parser):
    lineno = parser.stream.next().lineno
    value = parser.parse_expression()

    im = get_thumbnail(value.value, "100x100")

    parser.stream.expect('name:as')
    name = parser.stream.expect('name')
    body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endthumbnail'], drop_needle=True)
    # Use a local variable instead of a macro argument to alias
    # the expression.  This allows us to nest "with" statements.

    body.insert(0, nodes.Assign(nodes.Name(name.value, 'store'), im))

    return nodes.CallBlock(
            self.call_method('_render_block'), [], [], body).\
                set_lineno(lineno)

    def _render_block(self, caller=None):
        return caller()
```

My template:

```
{% thumbnail "jinja.png" as img %}
    {{ img.url }}
{% endthumbnail %}
```

But i get an `AttributeError: 'ImageFile' object has no attribute 'iter_child_nodes'`

It`s seems that i should pass a jinja2.nodes.Node object as a second parameter to nodes.Assign( ). How should i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by sending a get_thumbnail function into template:

```
from sorl.thumbnail.shortcuts import get_thumbnail
from coffin.template import Library
register = Library()

@register.object()
def thumbnail(file_, geometry_string, **options):
    try:
        im = get_thumbnail(file_, geometry_string, **options)
    except IOError:
        im = None
    return im
```

And now I can call it directly from template:

```
{% set image = thumbnail(image_object, params.size|default("100x100")) %}
```

There is no necessary in custom tag or filter.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I think you are just missing a "from sorl.thumbnail.shortcuts import get_thumbnail" in your templatetag file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something similar, suitable for use in 2016, using coffin's successor, [django-jinja](https://github.com/niwinz/django-jinja) --

```
from sorl.thumbnail.shortcuts import get_thumbnail
from django_jinja import library

@library.filter
def thumbnail(path, geometry, **options):
    return get_thumbnail(path, geometry, **options)
```